# Stop SQl Server connections in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, sqlconnection

I have SQL connections in a Excel file that I need them not to load when the file is opened. I have tried to remove connections from File-> Options-> Formulas and deactivate the Use table names in Query. The connections still appears.

[Query Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58ZXg.png)

Can someone help me please with a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate “automatically” background update of connections.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connection-properties-9d3599a9-e9b3-461d-99b2-c5505ddae6e0